# No manifests exist for the current culture

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, embedded-resource

teaching myself about .Net Core asp.

I have added a resource file to my solution.
I have added a test string to this resource file.
I am now trying to access this test string/key within my controller.

So, in my startup.cs I have this:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddLocalization(opts => { opts.ResourcesPath = "Resources"; });

    services.AddMvc()
       .AddViewLocalization(
            LanguageViewLocationExpanderFormat.Suffix,
                opts => { opts.ResourcesPath = "Resources"; })
    .AddDataAnnotationsLocalization();

    services.Configure<RequestLocalizationOptions>(
        opts =>
        {
            var supportedCultures = new List<CultureInfo>
            {
                    new CultureInfo("en-GB"),
                    new CultureInfo("en-US"),
                    new CultureInfo("en"),
                    new CultureInfo("fr-FR"),
                    new CultureInfo("fr"),
            };

            opts.DefaultRequestCulture = new RequestCulture("en");
            // Formatting numbers, dates, etc.
            opts.SupportedCultures = supportedCultures;
            // UI strings that we have localized.
            opts.SupportedUICultures = supportedCultures;
        });
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory, WorkerContext context)
{
    app.UseStaticFiles();

    var options = app.ApplicationServices.GetService<IOptions<RequestLocalizationOptions>>();
    app.UseRequestLocalization(options.Value);

    app.UseMvc(routes =>
    {
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "default",
            template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
    });
}
```

In my Controller I have this:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private readonly IStringLocalizer<HomeController> _localizer;
    public HomeController(IStringLocalizer<HomeController> localizer)
    {
        _localizer = localizer;
    }
}
```

My resource file stored here:

[image]

My properties for this resource file are:
[image]

I set a breakpoint here:

**_localizer = localizer;**

I inspect this variable and as you see the manifest has not been found...
[image]

What am i not understanding please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you just described my issue as I went through all of your steps, but it was nothing.

I noticed that localization required an extension class but the DLL for that extension was not in my dependencies. Anyway I used NuGet to install couple of dependencies and my project worked like a charm. Try to install the following and try again.

Microsoft.Extensions.Localization,
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Localization

Answer (score 2):

### Issue 1

Based on https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/localization

You're supposed to put your `Resources` in a folder called Resources under the root. You have it under the `Properties` folder...

This code block (slightly different from yours)
**Statup.cs**

```
services.AddLocalization(options => options.ResourcesPath = "Resources");
```

resolves to that folder for me in my projects.

[image]

---

### Issue 2

The other issue is your naming isn't done right. Take a look at the section called [Working With Resource Files](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/localization#working-with-resource-files) which will do a better job of explaining it to you than me putting it here.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I did initially had it in a Resources folder and i was changing things round ti get  this to work. Just in case I created again the Resources folder and out the resource file into it.  Unfortunately, it still cannot find it :(

Comment: @AndrewSimpson I also noticed, but your file name isn't the same as mine. I'm not sure if that's also part of it. You might want to look at the documentation link I provided at the top of my answer.

Comment: I renamed it to: Controllers.HomeController. Is this correct? the reason I ask is that I get a compile error stating...

Comment: @AndrewSimpson - `Contollers.HomeController.XX.resx` the `XX` is your language.

Comment: @AndrewSimpson take a look at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/localization#working-with-resource-files it tells you all about it.

Comment: Thanks for link. It seems I have been following an old tutorial with wrong info.  (not the adding the GB part to the file name - that was my mishap). i will read and get back to you. Thanks :)

Comment: Hi thanks for your continued help. I am still struggling with this.  Looking at that last link you gave me.. 1 minute (in that example) the name of the resource file is 'welcome.es.resx' and then the next I am supposed to call it Controllers.HomeController.XX.resx. As it was my language culture keeps on defaulting to en-US and not kept at en-UK. Which is fine. I changed the name of my file to Controllers.HomeController.US.resx. Yet still it tells me the resource file cannot be found

Comment: @AndrewSimpson If I'm not mistaken, I think you're supposed to use `xxx.en-US.resx`

Answer (score 0):

My resources also didn't work, so I checked the `IStringLocalizer.GetAllStrings()`, saw the same error "No manifests exist for the current culture" so went chasing that.

Turns out the only issue was my `resx` file was named wrong, it had to add the namespace (minus the assembly name) to the filename. That fixed the resources, they now work fine.

However, even with resources now working, the call to `IStringLocalizer.GetAllStrings()` still throws the same exception.

**Take home message: That exception doesn't necessarily mean your resources do not work.**

The [Troubleshoot ASP.NET Core Localization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/troubleshoot-aspnet-core-localization) page might also be a helpful resource.